# Why can't I set tableview background color to white?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

Whenever I do and run the app it's light gray. I've changed EVERY color I can and white just does not stay white. Every other color I've tried works, just not white.

I tried these 2

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
self.tableView.backgroundView!.backgroundColor = .white



self.tableView.backgroundColor = .white
```

And I've tried to just set it in storyboard to white

Comment: please show your code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @jawadAli I added them to my post

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the view with the correct rect:

```
    self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView(frame: self.tableView.frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for reasons I can't fathom when setting the TableView's View background colour to white or a light-grey colour in the XIB file. Any other colour worked just fine. Only fix I found was to set the background colour to white in the UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` function like so:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```